# How to get a realistic web load test result in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I've created a web load test for my site, ramping up from 1 to 300 users.  The performance recorded on the test is outrageous, totally off the scale from the worst performance I could imagine - imagine response times for a simple login script taking up to 10 minutes!

My immediate suspicion falls on the fact that I'm simulating 300 clients on a single computer.  I would guess that my own computer's processing power and internet bandwidth are much more of a bottleneck than the server.

Is there any better way of testing my web site's performance that will yield more realistic results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can run load tests from a developer machine but it's generally not recommanded for large load tests : you machine will host a web site, run a load test, simulate virtual users, store tests results in a local db ... It's easy to understand that your machine will become the *bottleneck* in your load test. It's only good for small smoke tests.

In order to simulate a lot of users, you'll set up what is known as a Load Test Rig.If possible try to Host your web site on a separate machine, and use TestController and Agents. The controller manages and coordinates the agent machines and the agents generate load against the application (hosted somewhere else).

I have been a user of Visual Studio Load Testing for 2 years, and I have found it very powerfull and easy to use. There are also many hidden of not documented features/properties that are very important to understand

- Percentage of New Users & Cache Control
- Think time between iterations
- Remote Test Settings (do not collect intellitrace, or run a asp.net profiling session)
  ...

Some of them are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404664(v=vs.100).aspx).

I also generally do not run load tests using a step pattern but a goal based pattern targeting 50% CPU on the web server.